# Excel Nested IF with SUMIF statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel Sheet Picture]

I have attached a picture of what I am trying to do, but I do not know how to go about doing it. So, what I want to do is this: my values are as follows.

i want to write an if statements of H=4, FM=8, FN=8, F=8 and I want to add those into a single cell based on the row itself.

It would be easier, I imagine, to show you. for example, I want b4=44 because it sums row 4 based on an if statement returning d4=4,e4=8,f4=8,j4=8,k4=8, r4=8.

I want the letters to return a number, which i know is an IF statement, but then i want to sum all those numbers on the IF statement.

I have seen you have to use sum(sumif(if statements nested like this, i have seen sumif(if statements nested but nothing seems to work for me and i have not found an example where you are summing an entire range based on the return of nested IF statements. in reality, because of this, i do not know if what i want to do is even possible.

any help is greatly appreacited.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(D4:R4,"H")*4+COUNTIFS(D4:R4,"F*")*8`.

Comment: I just got to work. I used:  =SUM(IF(D4:R4="H",4,IF(D4:R4="FM",8,IF(D4:R4="FN",8,0))))

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((LEFT(D4:R4)="H")*4)+((LEFT(D4:R4)="F")*8))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is COUNTIFS with `F*` to match all instances beginning with F.

```
=COUNTIFS(D4:R4,"H")*4+COUNTIFS(D4:R4,"F*")*8
```